# How to make a seal / badge / widget on Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Examples of what I want to achieve:

[See gif of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2DpB.gif)

https://sectigo.com/trust-seal

[See gif of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKvpG.gif)

https://www.carandtruckremotes.com/

[See gif of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egOTr.gif)

https://www.shopperapproved.com/

[See gif of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS4cI.gif)

https://www.carcovers.com/

Can anyone point me to a right direction on how to make functioning trust seal / badge / widget? As I understand there should be some API included. It should be able to recognize that it's on the right website / domain. I am working with django backend framework to make this app. I am looking to find how this kind of app is programmed on a backend.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to add a `trusted seal` to your site then this requires you to obtain a plan with a relevant company, e.g. [TrustedSite.com](https://www.trustedsite.com/start)

Once you do that, I believe the site performs an assessment on your site for security and vulnerability checks and the results of that determine the badge on display.

The badges are often an embedding of a given `HTML` code. For example, from the example you gave

[image]

Comment: Dear AzyCrw4282, thank you. Sorry, my question might have not been too clear. I am looking to find out on how this kind of app is made on the backend. I don't want to use let's say "TrustedSite" I am looking to find out how to make a system like that myself.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarification. Your current objective may be too broad to be covered in a single answer on S/O but I can recommend you the following. Reddit Community would be a good place to gather some information on how you can approach this as opposed to S/O. Observe related repos on GitHub-there's always a matching/similar one. I am not much exp in building such platform, but my instincts tells me that it would of-course require APIs to be built, ideally with `Django-rest-Framework`. Look into it...